# Generating a secure key that restricts a user to a particular radius

Tags: algolia

I was thinking of using Algolia's Secured API Keys feature to limit my users' queries to a particular geographic area (e.g., 50 miles around their home location). The idea was that users shouldn't be able to search the entire system, only the part of it that is relevant to them, thus limiting overall exposure of database. Does the API support anything like this, or do I need to use the tagging feature to do something less specific, e.g., tagging records by the user's home state ("New York") and then restricting access based on that tag?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do so by generating a specific API key with pre-filled search parameters for each of your user.

Each key will have a specific around lat lng parameter and a specific radius also.

The user will not be able to trick the key to use different pre-filled search parameters. But you can still use different parameters (that were not pre-filled).

First, you need to create a new search only api key in your dashboard.

Then, using the JavaScript (node.js) client for instance:

```
var public_key = client.generateSecuredApiKey('YourSearchOnlyApiKey', {aroundLatLng: '43.0909,23.99898', aroundRadius: 50 * 1000});
```

Then on the frontend, in the browser, using this new api key, your user will only be able to search for items around the provided latitude longitude with a 50km radius.

You can use any geo search parameter https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#geo-search-parameters.

More infos:

- https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/security
- https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js#security--user-api-keys

Every other API client has the same paragraph.